# Serial read not working properly

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to read some data from a serial port. I'm getting correct readings when using "cutecom" as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpkdL.png) but when doing serial read i'm losing some data. How do i solve this?

Here's my current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial
import time
try:
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB1',
        baudrate=115200, #8N1
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
    )
except:
    raise IOError
if (ser.isOpen()):
    ser.close()
ser.open()
def getdata():
    info = ''
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0: 
        info += str(ser.read())
        print info
    print '================='
    return info

ser.write('@01?C 1_@01?C 2_@02?C 1_@02?C 2\r')

time.sleep(0.0015)          # 0.0015 because anything more is giving the same result
print 'out:'                # but anything less screws up the read data even more
print getdata()
time.sleep(0.0015)
print 'out:'
print getdata()
time.sleep(0.0015)
print 'out:'
print getdata()
time.sleep(0.0015)
print 'out:'
print getdata()
```

Here is the output:

```
Precision-T1700: python ~/mobileman2/supermegabot/smb_test3.py 
out:
@
@0
@01
@01 
@01 C
@01 C=
@01 C=4
@01 C=43
@01 C=434
@01 C=4348
@01 C=43481
=================
@01 C=43481
out:
8
8
+
+
@
@0
@01
@01 
@01 C
@01 C=
@01 C=4
@01 C=43
@01 C=432
@01 C=4320
@01 C=43208
@01 C=432089
@01 C=432089
+01 C=432089
+01 C=432089
@01 C=432089
@01 C=432089
@02 C=432089
@02 C=432089
@02 C=432089
@02 C=432089
@02 C=332089
@02 C=382089
=================
@02 C=382089
out:
6
63
632
6329
6329
+329
+329
@329
@029
@029
@02 
@02 C
@02 C=
@02 C=3
@02 C=38
@02 C=381
@02 C=3810
@02 C=38104
@02 C=381046
@02 C=381046
+02 C=381046
+02 C=381046
=================
+02 C=381046
out:
=================

Precision-T1700:
```

Thanks

[Disregard this. I keep getting the error that says "too much code add more description" so i'm just gonna type this. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]

Comment: Buffers on serial connections are tiny, if you sleep you might miss some data.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getdata():
    info = ''
    while ser.inWaiting() > 0: 
        info += str(ser.readline())
        print info
    print '================='
    return info
```

might work better ... since it looks like the data is in lines

even better if you always know a packet is 15 characters or something just read the packet size `ser.read(15)`

serial is sort of lossy by nature so maybe you need to sample 3 times and poll which ever 2 answers match use that value ... (or maybe all of the 01 readings are the "same" so take the mode of that list, and the mode of 02 ) ... at a guess that integer is several readings that are bit twittled together